# Parallel port not working with an HP Laserjet 6L

Tags: printing, serial-port

I have laser hp printer but HP setup cant access LPT even I added my self to 
group.

```
sudo gpasswd -a slobodan lp
```

[HPLP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEe6C.png)

```
$ cat /etc/group
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:syslog,slobodan
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:slobodan
mail:x:8:
news:x:9:
uucp:x:10:
man:x:12:
proxy:x:13:
kmem:x:15:
dialout:x:20:slobodan
fax:x:21:
voice:x:22:
cdrom:x:24:slobodan
floppy:x:25:
tape:x:26:
sudo:x:27:slobodan
audio:x:29:pulse
dip:x:30:slobodan
www-data:x:33:slobodan
backup:x:34:
operator:x:37:
list:x:38:
irc:x:39:
src:x:40:
gnats:x:41:
shadow:x:42:
utmp:x:43:
video:x:44:
sasl:x:45:
plugdev:x:46:slobodan
staff:x:50:
games:x:60:
users:x:100:
nogroup:x:65534:
systemd-journal:x:101:
systemd-timesync:x:102:
systemd-network:x:103:
systemd-resolve:x:104:
systemd-bus-proxy:x:105:
input:x:106:
crontab:x:107:
syslog:x:108:
netdev:x:109:
messagebus:x:110:
uuidd:x:111:
ssl-cert:x:112:
lpadmin:x:113:slobodan
lightdm:x:114:
nopasswdlogin:x:115:
whoopsie:x:116:
mlocate:x:117:
ssh:x:118:
avahi-autoipd:x:119:
avahi:x:120:
bluetooth:x:121:
scanner:x:122:saned
colord:x:123:
pulse:x:124:
pulse-access:x:125:
rtkit:x:126:
saned:x:127:
slobodan:x:1000:
sambashare:x:128:slobodan
geoclue:x:129:
ftp:x:130:
wireshark:x:131:
guest-upsts0:x:999:
guest-z3ba9n:x:998:
guest-grs3jz:x:997:
```

And

```
$ sudo /usr/lib/cups/backend/parallel 
[sudo] password for slobodan: 
direct parallel:/dev/lp0 "HP LaserJet 6L" "HP LaserJet 6L LPT #1" "MFG:Hewlett-Packard;CMD SET:HP ENHANCED PCL5,PJL;MODEL:HP LaserJet 6L;CLS:PRINTER;DESCRIPTION:Hewlett-Packard LaserJet 6L Printer;REV:01;VER:0101;" ""
```